# Does the column have foreign key references

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query :

```
SELECT 
    cl.relname AS table_name, a.attname AS column_name, 
    a.atttypid AS type_name, co.confkey AS keys
FROM 
    pg_class cl, pg_attribute a, pg_constraint co
WHERE 
    cl.oid = a.attrelid 
    AND co.conrelid = cl.oid 
    AND a.attnum > 0
ORDER BY
    column_name
```

I have a database and there are o lot of tables inside, some of them has foreign keys (as I understand when the column from table 1 point on anouther column in table 2 it called, that first column has a foreign key, correct me if I'm wrong). So I need to show some information about every column of all the tables :

- Name of the table
- Name of the column
- Type
- does this column has a foreign key references?

I created small database and tested my query, results :

[image]

And as you see, foreign key is only for `House` column, but `nope` has the same value, and i need a mark only near `House`(from  table2).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I just want to show, how does this query works, and also what should i change to get information for every column, are there some foreign keys for this column or no. And what do you mean saying 'random SELECT'?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know those tables (pg_class etc) were system tables, I thought they were user tables... (I'm used to information_schema.)

Comment: hmmm... it's a nice idea to rewrite it using information_schema :) , but i also interested, how to get information using System Catalogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you're missing is a check for `a.attnum = ANY(co.conkey)`. But there are a few other things you need to consider:

- `pg_class` also contains indexes, views, sequences and types
- `pg_constraint` also contains primary keys, `CHECK` constraints, etc.
- Dropped columns are never removed from `pg_attribute`
- The catalogs also describe the catalog tables themselves, which you probably don't care about

With all of that in mind:

```
SELECT 
  n.nspname AS schema_name,
  cl.relname AS table_name,
  a.attname AS column_name, 
  a.atttypid AS type_name,
  co.confkey AS keys
FROM
  pg_class cl
  JOIN pg_namespace n ON
    n.oid = cl.relnamespace
  JOIN pg_attribute a ON
    a.attrelid = cl.oid
  LEFT JOIN pg_constraint co ON
    co.contype = 'f' AND
    co.conrelid = cl.oid AND
    a.attnum = ANY(co.conkey)
WHERE
  n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND
  cl.relkind = 'r' AND
  a.attnum > 0 AND
  NOT a.attisdropped
```